# Uvicorn server starts but "The connection has timed out" on the Browser

Tags: fastapi, uvicorn

When I execute the following code (basic Hello World from the doc):

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

And start the uvicorn server from my distant server (accessed through ssh) with:

```
uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload
```

And finally access https://MY_IP_SERVER:8000

I get:

> The connection has timed out

**Problem:** it used to work...

I tried to check all the processes corresponding to uvicorn and to kill them, I also restarted the server, but still the same

Any idea ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, haven't narrowed it down just yet.

Comment: I think this has something to do with your IP binding. In my case I'm not specifying any host and I can load the site using http://localhost:8000 but not http://127.0.0.1:8000